# I've written some VBA code, I need to pick the unique value (user) from a sheet and compare password,then change the password

Tags: excel, vba, userform

```
Dim oldpwd, newpwd, conpwd, usr As String

Dim x As Range

usr = Label6.Caption

newpwd = TextBox3.Value

oldpwd = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(usr,Worksheets("Info").Range("A:C"), 3, 0)
```

'how to use Replace the value of oldpwd?'

Comment: `Dim oldpwd, newpwd, conpwd, usr As String` declares `oldpwd, newpwd, conpwd` as variants but only `usr` as string. In any event, your question is on the vague side. It isn't clear what you are trying to do and what difficulty you are encountering. Could you distill this to a [mcve]?

Comment: A more fundamental issue -- are you really sure that you want to use Excel as a password manager? If security is a goal (and why use passwords if it wasn't?) this sounds like a very insecure approach.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Dim oldpwd As String, newpwd As String, conpwd As String, usr As String
Dim x As Range, m, c As Range, wsInfo as worksheet

usr = Label6.Caption
newpwd = TextBox3.Value  '<<< check for zero-length!
Set wsInfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Info")

m = Application.Match(usr, wsInfo.Range("A:A"), 0)
If Not IsError(m) Then
    Set c = wsInfo.Cells(m, "C")
    oldpwd = c.Value
    If oldpwd <> newpwd Then
        c.value = newpwd
    Else
        'passwords are the same
    End if
Else
    'user was not found
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the user cell first. The VLookup will only return the value.

Something like this:

```
Set userCell = Worksheets("Info").Range("A:C").Find(usr)
userCell.Value = newpwd
```